# How to get the amount of token sent to a smart contract via the fallback function in solidity

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Let's say I have a token A and a smart contract B.
A user sent some amount of A to to the contract B by direct transfer through his wallet.
In the fallback function of the smart contract B, how will I get the amount of token A that was sent?

msg.value did'nt give me anything since it's not Eth that was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your contract receives ERC-20 tokens, the `fallback()` function is not invoked - nor any other function. Meaning, your contract does not get notified about incoming ERC-20 transfers unless you pull them with `transferFrom()`.

```
contract YourContract {
    function pullTokens() external {
        // need to have prior approval
        tokenContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    }
}
```

*Note: Some other fungible token standards define these notification functions for recipient contracts - for example [ERC-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777) and its function `tokensReceived()`.*

Comment: Thanks, then, is there a way  to prevent  direct transfers of ERC-20 tokens to contracts and keep users to only use  the pullTokens function?

Comment: @Rayflex Unfortunately there's not. I'm not sure about your use case, but generally you can simply ignore the unwanted tokens. Or implement a custom function allowing to withdraw the unwanted tokens by an authorized address or by anyone. Pseudocde: `function withdraw() { if (nonWithdrawable[tokenAddress] == false) { tokenAddress.transfer(msg.sender, amount); }}`, where only the expected tokens have `nonWithdrawable` value set to `true`

Comment: I want to perform some actions upon receiving USDT tokens such us putting the sender address in a mapping of investors. If the sender transfers USDT directly to the contract I won't be able do so, and I can't neither provide a withdraw function as I won't know what amount was sent.

Comment: @Rayflex Then you'll need to use the `approve()` / `transferFrom()` approach.